# how to update kubelet and controller manager parameters in gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to update the following parameters in  kubelet and controller manager in gke for reducing node fault detection time.

kubelet: node-status-update-frequency
controller-manager: node-monitor-period
controller-manager: node-monitor-grace-period
controller-manager: pod-eviction-timeout

Can anyone please let me know how to update these parameters in gke?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update those parameters on GKE.
Generally speaking, it's not advisable to update these settings as there are potential side effects if many pods start to fail at the same time, especially as you increase the number of nodes.  GKE sets sane defaults for these parameters.

Comment: But I want to run my pods on small cluster i.e. 3-5 nodes and I want to reduce the node fault time to 3 seconds or below. I don't want default settings for small cluster as it gives me 30-40 seconds of node fault detection time.
Please suggest the option. Thanks

Comment: Hi Guys, Any ideas, please share ? Thanks

Comment: There really is not way for you to change the parameters for the controller-manager.  You could possibly modify the kubelet config, but it's definitely not advisable as it may break updates and upgrades.

So unfortunately there is no way to accomplish these specific tasks.

Comment: Thanks @Gari Singh for your response, appreciate.